# Change duration of setTimeout on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm working on this simple loop that display 1-20 numbers. It was displayed one by one with a duration of 500ms apart. what I'm trying to do is, when the loop is on 10 then I click the button it will show instantly the remaining 10 numbers.

Thanks.

```js
var duration = 500;
for(let i=0; i < 20; i++ ){
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('ul').append('<li>'+ (i+1) +'</li>')
  }, i * duration);
}

$('button').click(function(){
   duration = 0;
});
```

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  float:left;
  width: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #222;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<br>
<button>display all</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to have an array of functions that are `shift`ed and called on each interval. On click, clear the interval and `forEach` over the rest of the functions still in the array, and call them:

```js
var duration = 500;
const fns = [];
for(let i=0; i < 20; i++ ){
  const fn = () => $('ul').append('<li>'+ (i+1) +'</li>');
  fns.push(fn);
}
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  const fn = fns.shift();
  if (fn) fn();
  else clearTimeout(interval);
}, duration);

$('button').click(function(){
  fns.forEach(fn => fn());
  clearTimeout(interval)
});
```

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  float:left;
  width: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #222;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<br>
<button>display all</button>
```

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for help, Is there a way that we can just change the variable value?

Comment: Unfortunately no, once a timeout is set by `setTimeout`, the timeout duration can't be changed. For the general case, the timeout would have to be cleared and then re-called with the new duration.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a slightly different approach to the button click event, by emptying and rebuilding your `<ul>` list in the event that the button is clicked.

Something you also need to keep in mind is that your timeouts need to be cancelled when the button is clicked. To achieve this, you might consider storing each timeout's id, so that each timeout can be cleared when the button is clicked.

The following code is one approach to this, that minimises the amount of adjustment to your current code :

```js
    var duration = 500;

    // Declare timeout array to store timeout ids
    var timeouts = [];

    for(let i=0; i < 20; i++ ){

      // Store each timeout id, so that you can cancel them if 
      // button clicked
      timeouts[i] = setTimeout(function(){
         $('ul').append('<li>'+ (i+1) +'</li>')
      }, i * duration);

    }
    
    $('button').click(function(){
        
        // If button clicked, empty ul and repopulate it
        $('ul').empty()
    
      for(var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {

        // Clear timeout at i
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]) 

        // Add li element for i
        $('ul').append('<li>'+ (i+1) +'</li>') 
      }
    
    
       duration = 0;
    });
```

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  float:left;
  width: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #222;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<br>
<button>display all</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace loop with function instead, rest works fine:

```js
var duration = 500;

function range(i, n) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('ul').append('<li>' + (i) + '</li>')
    if (i < n) {
      range(i + 1, n);
    }
  }, duration);
}
range(1, 20);

$('button').click(function() {
  duration = 0;
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #222;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<br>
<button>display all</button>
```